# NavigationDrawer with SlidingPaneLayout in right content pane... possible?

Tags: android

I currently have a working NavigationDrawer main activity that swaps in a new fragment when the user selects an item from the nav drawer.  When one of the nav items is selected I would like to swap in a new fragment that uses a SlidingPaneLayout for it's layout... The current documentation suggests it should be used at the root level but doesn't specifically say it can't be used further down.. does anyone know if what I'm trying to accomplish is possible or supported?  Any help or suggestions on how to get it working or on an alternative way to implement a similar layout would be greatly appreciated.  thanks!

Comment: I am interested in similar thing. I want to implement SlidingPaneLayout inside a tab from the action bar. I really think it will be useful to use this in cases other than root level. Please comment.